# Tikz labelling picture

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have the following code. I, somehow, could not manage to number the whole figure. I have tried with label but, it does not show label at all.

```
\begin{figure}
\centering

\subfigure[Single Crossing]{\resizebox{0.4\textwidth}{!}{ %
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]
\draw (0,0) -- +(4,0) node[pos=0,left]{\tt\color{black}1};

\draw (0,-4)-- +(4,0) node[pos=0,left]{\tt\color{black}0};

\draw [red,line width=2pt, name path= F] (0,-4) -- (0.5,-4) to [out=20, in=195] (3.5,0)--(4,0);
\draw [blue, line width=2pt, name path= G] (0,-4) -- (1,-4) to [out=20, in=195] (3,0) -- (4,0);

\fill[gray,name intersections={of=F and G,total=\t}]
\foreach \s in {1,...,\t}{(intersection-2) node[left] {E}};

 \draw [fill] (0,-1.5) circle[radius=0.03];

 \draw [dashed,lightgray] (0,-1.5) node[left,black]{$p$} -- (2.12,-1.5) -- (2.12,-4);

 \draw [dashed,thick,gray] (2.12,-4) -- (2.12, -1)-- (0,-1)node(yline)[left,black]   {$p^{\prime}$};

 \draw [fill] (0,-1) circle [radius=0.03];

 \draw [fill=gray] (intersection-2) circle [radius=0.03];

\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Part of your code snippet is missing, a complete example would be better. Do you just want `\caption{figure desc.}` after the end of the `\subfigure`? Edit: Oh, and the `subfigure` package is deprecated (see http://www.ctan.org/pkg/subfigure), `subcaption` or `subfig` is usually recommended instead.

Comment: What do you mean with "number the whole figure"? What does this have to do with TikZ?

Comment: Note : I read here once the subcaption package was to be preferred for that kind of stuff, so please follow Torbjørn's advice. In it's documentation you'll find how to give a caption (with `\caption{your caption}`) to each subfigure and for the whole figure as well. Normally it should be out of the `\subfigure[]{...}` stuff.

Answer (score 2):

## Remarks

I extended your code to be a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228). Also, I added several captions to the figure. Furthermore, instead of the deprecated `sufigure`package the newer and favorable package `subcaption` is used.

## Implementation

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty} %for cropping
\usepackage{tikz,subcaption}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{subfigure}{0.8\linewidth}
    \centering
    \resizebox{0.4\textwidth}{!}{
      \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]
        \draw (0,0) -- +(4,0) node[pos=0,left]{\tt\color{black}1};
        \draw (0,-4)-- +(4,0) node[pos=0,left]{\tt\color{black}0};
        \draw [red,line width=2pt, name path= F] (0,-4) -- (0.5,-4) to [out=20, in=195] (3.5,0)--(4,0);
        \draw [blue, line width=2pt, name path= G] (0,-4) -- (1,-4) to [out=20, in=195] (3,0) -- (4,0);
        \fill[gray,name intersections={of=F and G,total=\t}]
        \foreach \s in {1,...,\t}{(intersection-2) node[left] {E}};
        \draw [fill] (0,-1.5) circle[radius=0.03];
        \draw [dashed,lightgray] (0,-1.5) node[left,black]{$p$} -- (2.12,-1.5) -- (2.12,-4);
        \draw [dashed,thick,gray] (2.12,-4) -- (2.12, -1)-- (0,-1)node(yline)[left,black]   {$p^{\prime}$};
        \draw [fill] (0,-1) circle [radius=0.03];
        \draw [fill=gray] (intersection-2) circle [radius=0.03];
      \end{tikzpicture}
    }
    \caption{Single Crossing}
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption{Overall caption}
  \label{fig:somefigure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

## Output

> [image]

Comment: Can you please include the subcaption solution just for completeness? I think that would be a better alternative for future visitor's attention. There is a readily made example in the manual of `subcaption`. Subfigure is obsolete and replaced by `subfig` though nowadays I tend to think that subcaption replaced both.

Comment: @percusse Thank you for your suggestion. You are right, of course. I replaced my initial `subfigure` solution instead of adding another solution, because I think it is better to not even cover deprecated packages.